# Symbol for continuous dual

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, continuous-homomorphisms

Let $X$ be a vector space. The dual is the set of all linear forms from $X$ to $\mathbb{F}$.(can be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) That is, $X^* = \operatorname{Hom}(X,\mathbb{F})$.

If $X$ is also Banach, the continuous dual is the set of all continuous maps in $X$. That is, $C(X,\mathbb{F}) \cap X^*$.

Is there a symbol for the continuous dual space? Wikipedia uses the prime $'$, but that coincides with derived sets and other common meanings of $'$. Some books simply use $X^*$ to refer to the continuous dual space.

Comment: In functional analysis, the dual space $X^*$ is defined to be the set of continuous linear functionals on $X$.

Comment: @QiyuWen That symbol is already used for the dual space(continuous or discontinuous). I know that some books use $X^*$ directly to refer to the continuous dual space, but I want a distinction between the two.

Comment: Given a vector topology, we are almost always interested only in continuous linear functionals. Both the notation and the term "dual space" imply continuity in topological vector spaces. In fact, some professors I know do not even realize the existence of an "algebraic" definition of dual space. There is no widely accepted distinct notations, because there is no need.